# Why declaring and assigning values to array type object is throwing out of bound error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have defined this:

```
DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[] HeaderOperation = new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[] { };
HeaderOperation[0].DAUNO = Convert.ToString(dr["Duration"]);
HeaderOperation[0].DAUNE = Convert.ToString(dr["DurationUnit"]);
```

But it throws error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

`DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation` is of type array.

Comment: what is exactly the definition of DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation ?

Comment: also you didn't specify the length of the array  `new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[] { }`.

Comment: You created a new array of length 0 - it doesn't contain any elements. Depending on whether or not `DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation` is a struct or class will change whether you just need to change the length of the array or do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add length specifier to declare array. Length specifier indicates that how many elements are contained by your array. See: [Single-Dimensional Arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays)

```
DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[] HeaderOperation = new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[1];
HeaderOperation[0] = new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation()
{
    DAUNO = Convert.ToString(dr["Duration"]),
    DAUNE = Convert.ToString(dr["DurationUnit"])
};
```

Or you can use this [Array Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization) as follow.In this case, the length specifier is not needed because it is already supplied by the number of elements in the initialization list.

```
DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[] HeaderOperation = new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation[]
{
    new DT_OrderResponseOrderHeaderOperation()
    {
        DAUNO = Convert.ToString(dr["Duration"]),
        DAUNE = Convert.ToString(dr["DurationUnit"])
    }
};
```